# Find and replace a lot of <a> tags, but the url are different? Is there some way to do it?

Tags: html, replace

I have a page that I need to fix..

There are thousands of `<a>` tags like `<a href="kl1j23l123l12j3">` that I need to get rid off, but the problem is that each `<a>` tag has a different url in them (href attribute). So, I am wondering if there is some advanced way to get rid of the whole anchor/link but keep the link-text, as that would save me a whole lot of time.

***Example***

```
Input : <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow.com</a>
Output: StackOverflow.com
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want to kill all links on your page? How do you differentiate good links from bad?

Comment: Whats the difference between <a" and ">" and "<a>" and ">" ?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. Between "<a" and ">".

Comment: is this what you want? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/feugu/) Click the links the value of each anchor

Comment: he wants to remove all anchor tags but keep the link-text, but, since the href attribute is different for each link, he can't use the search/replace function inside the editor

Comment: What if I just want to get rid off all the links at once by using Find and Replace function?

Comment: since the href-attribute differs, I don't think that's possible by just using the find/replace function inside the editor..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a solution using JavaScript and jQuery. It also can be tweaked to only get the values of links that do not start with `http`. I wasn't quite sure whether this is relevant according to the links in the question.

```
// get all links within the document
​var links = $('a');

// simply get all link texts
var x = links.text();​​​​​​

// or just get all links that are like 'kl1j23l123l12j3' as they don't start with 'http'
var x = links.filter('[href^=http]').text();
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rg3ET/

Instead of applying them all together into one variable ("`x`") you could of course loop through them and output them individual.

Answer (score 0):

**The following would work under the assumption that each anchor tag is on its own line.**

Example:

```
<a href="myref">asdf</a>
<div>
</div>
<a href="myref2">asdf2</a>
```

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has a regex find and replace feature, which may work for your need.

1. Replace all `</a>` tags with nothing
2. Use a regex to find all `<a href="anything">` and replace with nothing.

The following image shows what I did for step 2. You can see that I used a regex of `<a .*>`. For this to work properly, there should only be one `>` character per line. Otherwise, the regex will make the longest possible match, possibly including a bunch of other tags. This is why I said the procedure would only work for anchor tags that are on their own lines.

[image: Step 2 Find and Replace]

In case you can't see the image (again, this only works:

1. From Notepad++ menu: **Search > Replace**
2. Select **Regular expression**
3. In **Find what** box, put `<a .*>`
4. Click **Replace All**